# Using em or rem when making layouts

Tags: css, layout

I've made visual layout on Sketch to my site, and noted every pixel between elements or how large words are. But I was confused when I started to do the CSS layout element which using the units.

I know that it's a better strategy to set up the `html {font-size: 62.5%;}` to make `1em = 10px;` instead of using `px` to make the layout. However, I met so many times of the offset when I was trying to make a layout when using em.

Here's the question, why we use **em** when we can use **rem**? And when is the right time to use **rem**? (Not caring about browser supporting issue)

P.S.: I've already known the difference between these two.

Answer (score 2):

`em` and `rem` are different with respect to rendering font-size. Check the [**CSS Ruler**](http://katydecorah.com/css-ruler/) for better understanding.

`em` should be used when you want to use different font relative sizes within/between different elements.

`rem` doesn't have any parent other than `html`.

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.font-sizing {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.em {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.rem {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="font-sizing">
  <span class="em">I am relative to parent element. So I have font-size of 12x3 = 36px.</span>
  <br>
  <span class="rem">I am relative to root element. So I have font-size of 10x3 = 30px.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I know the difference, but is there any practice to use these two?

Comment: Check my second line. If you need to have different sizes within a parent. This link will help you more: https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

Answer (score -1):

`em` is relative to the parent, `rem` relative to the root `(html)` tag.

`rem` is a more stable and predictable choice then.

Comment: That's what I've already know. So why and when is the best time to use em?

Comment: @ChenghuaYang obviously when you want your sizes depend on the parent

Comment: Any example, please?